# Error updating MySQL field

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update 2 fields (name and phone_number) in a MySQL table. The 'name' fields updates to zero while the 'phone_number' field does not update at all. Where is this problem coming from. This is my query:

```
$update = "UPDATE users SET name = :name AND phone_number = :phone_number WHERE id = :id";
$db->query($update, array('name' => $_POST['name'], 'phone_number' => $_POST['phone_number'], 'id' => $_SESSION['id']));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Between two `set` clause, you should use `,` instead of `and`.

Try to change

```
$update = "UPDATE users SET name = :name AND phone_number = :phone_number WHERE id = :id";
```

to

```
$update = "UPDATE users SET name = :name, phone_number = :phone_number WHERE id = :id";
```